# Hosting multiple distinct folders for distinct domains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, web-hosting

I have a VPS that I've installed a Apache Web Server on. What I want to do is forward my own website domains to that server and host those websites' files inside my Apache Web Server. As far as I understand a DNS server is required to manage which domain is hosted where (IP-wise). But what I want to do is host my websites under the same IP address, the one that my web server has. How can I separate those websites' files inside my web server so I don't have to use `http://host/foo` for `www.foo.com` and `http://host/bar` for `www.bar.com`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technology that you are looking for is [name based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html). Typically you would have DNS configured to point the domains to the IP of your server. Apache then uses the information in the [Host:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) header to serve the information from the correct vhost.

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80 

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName foo.example.com
    Serveralias www.foo.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/foo.example.com/root
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName bar.example.com
    Serveralias www.bar.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/bar.example.com/root
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the logic and also giving an example, appreciated.