# How do I point a domain to a specific directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, domain-name-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hosting multiple distinct folders for distinct domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/423644/hosting-multiple-distinct-folders-for-distinct-domains)

I have two domains pointing to the same IP address.

They both go to the directory `/public_html/www/`.

What is the best way to make the home directory of one of the domains `/public_html/www/somethingelse/`?

Comment: This is not a [tag:php] question.

Comment: umm [vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: not dns question either

Answer (score 1):

Add a new virtual host entry in your httpd.conf like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /public_html/www/somethingelse/
  ServerName www.yourdomain.com

  # Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Read this for more info : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html